# Constant breakpoints? How to remove them?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, breakpoints

I downloaded a project made with Delphi 2009,which is also what I use,however there is one breakpoint that I just can't remove.If I try to remove it,its being executed again after the program is executed.

I met such things in other debuggers known as Hardware breakpoints,but this is not important.How do I remove the breakpoint?

**EDIT:** [Article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31263) about those breakpoints,but It doesn't explain how to remove them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, you can't turn these off in the IDE, as Rob says, this is persisted in the .dsk file.

You don't have to delete the file (and all of your other settings), though.  you can just open it up in a text editor and find and edit the following section:

**[Breakpoints]**

Answer (score 8):

View->Debug Windows->Breakpoints.

I'm very dissapointed at those articles.They explain how to add something,but not how to remove it.

Comment: "Those articles"? You've only cited one. It is about special non-breaking breakpoints, and it assumes you already know how to use ordinary breakpoints. Anyone who knows how to use ordinary breakpoints knows that the usual way of removing them is simply to click in the gutter, the same way they're created. Why would anyone expect it to be any different for special breakpoints?

Comment: Anyway, if you can remove your breakpoint with the breakpoint debugger window even when you can't remove it by clicking in the gutter, then this is a good answer. +1.

Comment: Yes,that's the problem I had.Couldn't remove it in the left tab as normal breakpoints.

Answer (score 6):

Breakpoints are stored in the *dsk* file for your project. Close your project, delete that file, and re-open the project. All breakpoints should be gone. (Other window-layout customizations will be gone, too. You'll have to restore those preferences manually.)