# Is Delphi or BDS IDE capable of saving source-code breakpoints?

Tags: delphi, ide, workspace

Should be part of project *workspace* (*desktop* in Borland terms), dont you think? I suspect answer is **NO**, but if it is not so, please include details how to configure it.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? I'm using D2007 and XE, and both of them save breakpoints if you check "Project Desktop" in Tools|Options|Environment Options|Autosave options.

Comment: @Ken White, this is most likely version-independent, thats why i used "Delphi or BDS" (as IDE branches). eg: configured D7 restored breakpoint(s) successfully, yet sharing desktop files between IDE version still causes a problems.

Comment: Yes. And now, Delphi XE can also save the code BOOKMARKS (thanks god this long awaited feature was finally implemented).

Comment: @Altar, dunno, never tried XE (working in D2010 mostly). I always seen code bookmark as something *volatile* (easy to unset with mistype), so i dont have opinion about it (may be will find useful after next upgrade)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delphi stores breakpoints in the `[Breakpoints]` section of your project's *.dsk* file. Make sure that file is writable, and make sure your source-control system isn't accidentally clobbering it.

A couple of years ago, someone asked about the opposite problem: [Constant breakpoints? How to remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213793/33732)